# How to use Margins in Expo?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, react-navigation

I am creating this project on Expo (Snack), on a **Newsletter App**, and i came got this:

[Expected Output vs Actual Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gkykz.png)

The Web Preview is the output I expect in the Android App as well.

According to me, there is a problem with the margins or something.

[Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@dipamsen/newsletter-app)

This is the Button Component which i used:

```js
<View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
  <TouchableOpacity style={this.props.style}
    onPress={this.props.onPress}>
    <Text
      style={{
        alignSelf: 'center',
        justifySelf: 'center',
        fontSize: 18,
      }}
      onPress={this.props.onPress}>
      {this.props.name}
    </Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
</View>

// Styles: 

borderColor: 'black',
borderWidth: 2,
marginHorizontal: 'auto',
marginVertical: 15,
padding: 5,
width: 200,
height: 60,
justifyContent: "center",
borderRadius: 10
```

[Full Code](https://snack.expo.io/@dipamsen/newsletter-app)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add this style to your button container it will flex and center your elements:

````
<View style={{
    flex: 1, 
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'}}>
    <Button name="Read a Joke" style={styles.button}
            onPress={() => { this.props.navigation.navigate('JokeScreen') }} />
    <Button name="Horoscope" style={styles.button}
            onPress={() => { this.props.navigation.navigate('FutureScreen') }} />
    <Button name="Top News" style={styles.button}
            onPress={() => { this.props.navigation.navigate('NewsScreen') }} />
    <Button name="Weather" style={styles.button}
            onPress={() => { this.props.navigation.navigate('WeatherScreen') }} />
</View>
    ```
````

Comment: Thanks a lot! That saved me a lot of time.